# Dynamically adding html.TextAreaFor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a text area element (using TextAreaFor) to a modal body. For demonstrations sake, I have two buttons. When one is clicked a TextBoxFor element is added to the modal body. When the other button is click a TextAreaFor element is added instead.

TextBoxFor works fine but I'm having issues getting the text area to render properly. I'm only a beginner with JavaScript but it seems the closing tag of the textarea element is causing the string to end before the final '>' has been reached.

So the button is clicked, and the html is added:

```
btn.onclick = function () {
$('.modal-body').html('<label>Question Label</label>@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Response, new { @class = "form-control" })');
modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

However this renders as:

```
$('.modal-body').html('<label>Question Label/label><textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Response" name="Response" rows="2">X
</textarea>
```

With the 'X' being were I am getting the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error. Any advise about how to get around that would be much appreciated.

Comment: It should tell you which line the Syntax error is on... click it and it should be underlined. This should be simple for you to do.

Comment: I know exactly where the error is (where I put the X). But I can't figure out how to get @Html.TextAreaFor(...) to render as one string. I feel like it should be easy but been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: any reason you can't just use `<textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Response" name="Response" rows="2">X</textarea>` instead of textareafor?

Comment: I feel a little embarrassed. Thanks Pete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var counter=0;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
    
    if(counter>=5){
    alert("you can insert only 5 textareas")}
    else{
    
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
       .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv');

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Question Label </label>' + '<textarea rows=5 cols=50 name="textbox" id="textbox" value="" >');

  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
  counter++;
  }
  })
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
```

The counter variable is to ensure no more than 5 textareas are added.